# Some products not showing up on frontend after magmi import

Tags: category, products, magmi, category-products

After importing 277 products with magmi to magento 230 of the products are not showing up on the frontend.  They are on the Backend under managage prodocts and are 277 are shown to be assigned to a category.

So far I've

- cleared the cache
- re-indexed
- made sure the product is assigned to a category
- made sure the product is In Stock
- made sure the product has a qty assigned
- Going to a missing products URL gives a 404
- Tried deleting and re-adding products

Below is sample from the CSV I imported into magmi, the first one does not show successfully on the frontend but the second one does.

```
sku manufacturer    name    attribute_set   subgroup_desc   category_ids    type    configurable_attributes hoi_conf_ring_size  hoi_conf_frame_size description short_description   hoi_manufacturer_sku    price   special_price   rrp qty is_in_stock manage_stock    use_config_manage_stock status  visibility  weight  manufacturer_info   tax_class_id    store   thumbnail   small_image image   media_gallery
DKLPU1  Brand 1 Large Celtic Knot Pendant   Jewellery   Pendant 230,182,211 simple              Large Celtic Knot Pendant   Large Celtic Knot Pendant       48.95           10  1   1   1   1   Catalog, Search 0   Brand 1 Taxable Goods   admin   DKLPU1.jpg  DKLPU1.jpg  DKLPU1.jpg  DKLPU1.jpg
MAUCR4/S    Brand 2 Medium Silver Circles Pendant   Jewellery   Pendant 230,182,211 simple              Medium Silver Circles Pendant   Medium Silver Circles Pendant       183         10  1   1   1   1   Catalog, Search 0   Brand 2 Taxable Goods   admin   MAUCR4.jpg  MAUCR4.jpg  MAUCR4.jpg  MAUCR4.jpg
```

I had success importing 3 other batches of products with magmi but am not sure what to do.

Comment: Did you try and save one of the products? Check if that solves it

Comment: yes it didn't and I didn't get any errors

Comment: But still doesn't show up in the shop?

Comment: @SanderMangel, I just tried your suggestion again and I get an sql error I either missed or didn't get before `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hoi_local_1708_1504`.`rrd_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`, CONSTRAINT `FK_3F79FDC5C1B6C839E54F0943BD97D8F9` FOREIGN KEY (`value_id`) REFERENCES `rrd_catalog_product_entity_media_g), query was: INSERT INTO `rrd_catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` (`value_id`, `store_id`, `label`, `position`, `disabled`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

Comment: @SanderMangel, actuall, I tried saving again and I got no error but it did still does not show on frontend

Comment: Hm, not sure what it could be. Rarely use Magmi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in the end the problem was very obvious but I some how missed it.  Magmi imported the products as *Not Visible Individually* for some reason, even though I specified in the CSV that their visibility be *Catalog, Search*.

Anyway it was easily fixed from the admin by updating the attributes from the Manage Products section, can't believe it took me so long to spot!

To stop Magmi from converting some simple products to *Not Visible Individually* you have to change it's configuration for **Configurable Item processor v1.3.7**.  Change **Force simples visibility** to **No**.